# Error: no suitable constructor after update Android Studio from 0.6.1 to 0.8.9

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I've this error:

```
Error:(78, 56) error: no suitable constructor found for ImageViewTouch(Viewpager_activity)
constructor ImageViewTouch.ImageViewTouch(Context,AttributeSet,int) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor ImageViewTouch.ImageViewTouch(Context,AttributeSet) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
```

But this error I came out only after update Android Studio from 0.6.1 to 0.8.9, I did not have that error before the upgrade, in fact, the code that I put below worked perfectly before the update.
At most, I have the application with that code on the Nexus 5, and has no problems.

**Viewpager_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="#00A600"
        android:id="@+id/layoutesterno">

        <com.ruar.imagegallery.app.ImageViewTouchViewPager
            android:id="@+id/imagepager"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/relativeLayout" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
            android:background="#008A00">

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/saveBtn"
                android:background="@drawable/save"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="62dp"
                android:id="@+id/shareBtn"
                android:background="@drawable/share"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/saveBtn"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="62dp"
                android:id="@+id/setasBtn"
                android:background="@drawable/setaswallpaper"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/saveBtn"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/info"
        android:background="@drawable/info"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/bugimg"
        android:background="@drawable/bug"
        android:layout_below="@+id/info"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/info"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/info" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Viewpager_activity.java**

```
public class Viewpager_activity extends Activity
{
    int position;
    int img_id;
    Grid_adapter grid_adapter;
    String nomeimmagine;
    int i;
    final List<ImageViewTouch> images = new ArrayList<ImageViewTouch>();
    public static  String[][] galleryArrayThumb = ImmaginiThumb.thumbs;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.viewpager_layout);

            ImageLoader_Grid imageLoader = new ImageLoader_Grid(this.getApplicationContext());

            final Intent intent = getIntent();
            img_id = (Integer) intent.getExtras().get("img");
            position = (Integer) intent.getExtras().get("id");

            grid_adapter = new Grid_adapter(this, galleryArrayThumb[img_id]);
            nomeimmagine = LazyAdapter.titoli[img_id];
            setTitle(nomeimmagine);

            for (i = 0; i < grid_adapter.getCount(); i++)
            {
                 final ImageViewTouch imageViewTouch = new ImageViewTouch(this);

                 Picasso.with(Viewpager_activity.this)
                        .load(galleryArrayThumb[img_id][i])
                        .fit()
                        .centerInside()
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.loading)
                        .into(imageViewTouch);

                //imageLoader.DisplayImage(galleryArrayThumb[img_id][i], imageViewTouch);
                images.add(imageViewTouch);
            }

            ViewPager viewPager = (ImageViewTouchViewPager) findViewById(R.id.imagepager);
            viewPager.setAdapter(new Viewpager_adapter(images));
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
            viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        trimCache(Viewpager_activity.this);
                        Log.i("VP_cache", "Cache liberata");
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position1) {
                    position = position1;
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {}
            });
}//fine viewpager_activity
```

The error is in this line and the column is where there is written "this", that is, the contex of ImageViewTouch:

```
final ImageViewTouch imageViewTouch = new ImageViewTouch(this);
```

I've tried also these codes:

```
final ImageViewTouch imageViewTouch = new ImageViewTouch(Viewpager_activity.this);
final ImageViewTouch imageViewTouch = new ImageViewTouch(getApplicationContext());
```

But it does not change anything , I still get that error

**The other error is this:**

```
Error:(36, 41) error: no suitable constructor found for ImageViewTouch(Context)
constructor ImageViewTouch.ImageViewTouch(Context,AttributeSet,int) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor ImageViewTouch.ImageViewTouch(Context,AttributeSet) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
```

And the java code is this

**Viewpager_adapter.java**

```
public class Viewpager_adapter extends PagerAdapter
{
    private List<ImageViewTouch> imageViewTouches;

    public Viewpager_adapter(List<ImageViewTouch> imageViewTouches)
    {
        this.imageViewTouches = imageViewTouches;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return imageViewTouches.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position)
    {
        ImageViewTouch imageViewTouch = new ImageViewTouch(container.getContext());
        imageViewTouch = (ImageViewTouch) imageViewTouches.get(position);
        imageViewTouch.setScaleType(ImageViewTouch.ScaleType.MATRIX);

        container.addView(imageViewTouch);

        return imageViewTouch;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        ImageViewTouchViewPager pager = (ImageViewTouchViewPager) container;
        View recycledView = (View) object;
        pager.removeView(recycledView);
    }
}
```

And the line of error is this:

```
ImageViewTouch imageViewTouch = new ImageViewTouch(container.getContext());
```

And more specifically , this part of the code string:

```
new ImageViewTouch(container.getContext());
```

***I repeat before updating Android Studio everything worked smoothly.***
Thanks in advance, and if you need other codes put them

Comment: what is ImageViewTouchViewPager ?

Comment: It is the viewpager with which I can use the zoom for pictures

Comment: Sorry what is ImageViewTouch ? is your custom class then post code.

Comment: ImageViewTouchViewPager it's a custom Viewpager, and ImageViewTouch is a class of ImageViewZoom, a libray of [sephirot74 library](https://github.com/sephiroth74/ImageViewZoom)

Comment: Try this new ImageViewTouch(container.getContext(),null,0); or new ImageViewTouch(container.getContext(),null); In ImageViewTouch class not constructor declare with only context parameter.

Comment: Thank you very much, you're my savior, now it's back to work perfectly.

Comment: @Matto,Glad to help you i put as ans so you can accept and upvote it.

Comment: Doh now viewpager doesn't work, show first image, then when i swipe  no longer appear on the images

Comment: In instantiateItem please replace this : ImageViewTouch imageViewTouch = new ImageViewTouch(container.getContext(),null); or ImageViewTouch imageViewTouch = new ImageViewTouch(container.getContext(),null,0);

Comment: Please check my updated ans.

Comment: I make a new discussion for the new error, thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

In ImageViewTouch class two overloaded constructor define like :

```
ImageViewTouch(Context,AttributeSet) and ImageViewTouch(Context,AttributeSet,int)
```

And your are trying to initialize ImageViewTouch object using this constructor which is not define in  ImageViewTouch class:

```
ImageViewTouch(Context)
```

So try to use one overloaded constructor like :

```
new ImageViewTouch(container.getContext(),null,0) or  new ImageViewTouch(container.getContext(),null)
```

In ViewPager like :

```
ImageViewTouch imageViewTouch = new ImageViewTouch(container.getContext(),null); or ImageViewTouch imageViewTouch = new ImageViewTouch(container.getContext(),null,0);
```

Comment: Compiles, but image does not display for some reason. Thanks anyway, good answer